# Corel Draw X7: Some objects corrupt EPS File Exported, is there any reason?

Tags: export, corel-draw, eps

In my process here I need some outputs as EPS files. But when export that, the EPS file is corrupted, not displays anything and not opens in any app (and even errors in Illustrator.)

[image: Adobe Illustrator Error at open file, which actually not opens file!]

I found that there is some objects cause this problem. I link that objects in [this CDR](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cLLoazLT8vJGUTw0nVFP2BzpYXLNe-x6) file. [Also EPS file is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11oWVO2LbZoJcU7zIixSFEFpM_Pebs6gu).

(Image posted as reference)
[image]

If any one knows what is the issue, or if there is any workarounds please comment.

Comment: Which objects did you find that are causing the problem?  I can't open either of the files in Illustrator, although Inkscape opens the CDR file. Have you tried another format like PDF instead?

Comment: Yep! PDF is OK. As I checked the objects looks like the whole of em are problems! Was there everything OK with exporting in Inkscape?

Comment: I don't know if "everything" was OK, since I don't know what the CDR file is supposed to contain. I saw something that looks like a clock face.  IF PDFs are OK, then why not use that format instead?

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with an export I made and opening it on my version of illustrator, except a font issue.

Corel Draw

[image]

Illustrator

[image]

So probably you have an installation problem, either with Corel Draw or with Illustrator.

But still, I recommend that you clean your original file, removing, for example, the unnecessary rectangle.

A methodology to solve this issues is simply making a copy, and removing some objects and find where the problem could be. In this case was the text. Convert that to curves before exporting.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found that if, at some point, you make a figure semi/transparent and then return it to transparency = 0, its EPS exported version gets corrupted. You connot even re-import it to Corel Draw: you get a series of points instead of the original figure.

Making a copy to another document or "cleaning" the one you are working on, doesn´t solve the problem. You must draw it again.